# How to backup modified record or field value?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, administration, process-builder

I have few records in one custom object. If some one modify any record, I need to store the modified data.

[image]

In above picture, if someone modify Answer field value to 10000, i need to know the past data($250000). Where can i store the modified value and how can make it.

I tried with this query but but i couldn't find old value of field

[image]

Comment: enable 'track field history' for the object, then select the fields you want to track.

Comment: Chris, did you ever try it? Are you still working on this project?

Comment: Hi @Adrian Larson I'm still working on it. How to make a process to store all modified values of the filed. If you have anything that would be good for me.

Comment: @chris My step-by-step instructions seem pretty thorough from my perspective. Did you try following them?

Comment: Yeah  I tried that but I'm not able to get modified values as showing in above picture I've updated. I can't see the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Saumya has pointed you in the right direction. You can do it via history tracking on object. Make sure that you have turned on Track Field history on the object then track the history for that field. [History Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history_for_standard_objects.htm&language=en)

If that doesn't suffices your requirement, you can create a custom field by the name OLD ANSWER VALUE and populate that in a before update trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest implementation is indeed to enable `Field History Tracking` on your object. Here is a detailed breakdown of the steps to take:

1. Navigate to `Setup` > `Create` > `Objects` > `Question & Answer Detail`.
2. Click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button.
3. Check the `Track Field History` box.
4. Click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.
5. Click the <kbd>Set History Tracking</kbd> button.
6. Select the fields you would like to track.
7. Click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.

---

Now, when you make changes to that field, you will be able to query them in a few different ways:

```
SELECT Field, OldValue, NewValue FROM MyObject__history
```

OR

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Field, OldValue, NewValue FROM Histories) FROM MyObject__c
```

You can also add them as a `Related List` to your `Page Layout`. The list name would look like `Question & Answer Detail History`.